# WPF DataGrid ComboBox Column: Propagating Header Combobox throughout column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox, datagridcolumn

Hey there! Here's my question:

I've got a Datagrid in WPF and I have a first column that is a DataGridComboBoxColumn.

What I'd like to do is to have a header for that column also with a combobox: altering the header with propagate throughout the column.

I can get this done visually, but when I submit the data, the list that is bound with the Datagrid does not carry the new combobox values.

```
<dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding BIBStatus}"                                            
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource typeStatus}}" 
                           Width="0.20*">
                    <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Built-In Bridge"/>
                                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding BIBStatus}" 
                                          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource typeStatus}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>                                
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

In the ComboBox_SelectionChanged I have the following code:

```
DataGridColumn comboCol = this.gridResults.Columns[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.gridResults.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ComboBox myCmBox = (comboCol.GetCellContent(this.gridResults.Items[i]) as ComboBox);

            myCmBox.SelectedValue = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue;
        }
```

When I submit the data, I submit the list that is DataContext to the Datagrid; if I change the value of the first column addressing a row at a time, i.e. clicking the cell with the combobox in each row, the values are propagated to the list in DataContext, however if I change the value of the first column by the header it does not.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I'm guessing it's the way I affect each row, but I've tried SelectedValue, SelectedItem and SelectedIndex... all to no avail.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Since you're doing 2-way databinding, changing the data source should change the combobox's selecteditem. What happens when you directly set BIBStatus?

Comment: I thought of that :) but the problem is that it only updates each row's combobox when i click it for editing... otherwise each row remains the same.

I'm guessing the issue might be with triggering the SelectionChanged event in each row's combobox, since the databinding works when I select the value in each row. When I edit the comboboxes' values in code behind, that SelectionChanged event is not triggered, because it does not happen in the UI... any guesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have solved it... or at least disguised it...

```
DataGridColumn comboCol = this.gridResults.Columns[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.gridResults.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ComboBox myCmBox = (comboCol.GetCellContent(this.gridResults.Items[i]) as ComboBox);
            myCmBox.SelectedItem = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
        }

        if (this._results != null)
        {
            foreach (Device device in _results)
            {
                device.BIBStatus = (TypeStatus)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TypeStatus), ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue);
            }
        }
```

I tried to change only the datacontext and hope for the two-way binding to work, but it only did when I focused on each row's combobox. So I thought: "why not both ways?"
As you can see, I change both each combobox's selecteditem and each device's BIB status (the datacontext part). This way I get the desired effect.

However I do not think this solution is the best one and I'm still hoping there is a way I can do this without being a scoundrel.

Any suggestions are still welcome!